# Submitting ios app with hackintosh

Tags: ios, hackintosh

I developed my app on hackintosh and also sucesfully uploaded build for testing. I am wondering if I can just submit for review?
Have somebody ever heard of app being reject because it was submitted with hackintosh?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store policies.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Apple policy, not programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in 2011 I used to develop apps on virtual machine with OSX running under window XP. Successfully submitted several app versions.